# How can I get a Quotes instance into an Expr in Scala 3 macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

I have this:

```scala
def myMacroImpl[T:Type](t: Expr[T])(using quotes:Quotes): Expr[String] = {

  def fooFn(): Expr[(Any,StringBuilder) => StringBuilder] = 
    // quotes visible here

    val qq = Expr(quotes) //wrap quotes in Expr to access inside Expr below
    ‘{(a:Any, sb:StringBuilder) =>
        implicit val qt:Quotes = $qq
        // use qt here for something that needs a Quotes instance, for ex reflection
        sb.apply(“ok”)
     }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get something like this, coming from where I actually call my top-level macro:

```
[error] 16 |  println(co.blocke.scala_reflection.ZType.myMacro(person))
[error]    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |Exception occurred while executing macro expansion.
[error]    |java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
[error]    |    at scala.runtime.Scala3RunTime$.assertFailed(Scala3RunTime.scala:11)
[error]    |    at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$Ref$.apply(QuotesImpl.scala:444)
[error]    |    at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$Ref$.apply(QuotesImpl.scala:443)
[error]    |    at co.blocke.scala_reflection.ZType$given_ToExpr_Quotes$.apply(ZType.scala:32)
[error]    |    at co.blocke.scala_reflection.ZType$given_ToExpr_Quotes$.apply(ZType.scala:30)
[error]    |    at scala.quoted.Expr$.apply(Expr.scala:37)
[error]    |    at co.blocke.scala_reflection.ZType$.fooFn$1(ZType.scala:76)
[error]    |    at co.blocke.scala_reflection.ZType$.myMacroImpl(ZType.scala:121)
```

Quotes didn't have an Expr converter, so I added this:

```scala
  given ToExpr[Quotes] with {                               
    def apply(x: Quotes)(using q:Quotes) = {
      import q.reflect._
      Ref(defn.AnyClass).appliedToType(TypeRepr.typeConstructorOf(x.getClass)).asExpr.asInstanceOf[Expr[Quotes]]
    }
  }
```

Something in my gut tells me I'm doing this the hard way--and its clearly not working, but I don't know the answer.  How can I get a Quotes instance visible/"passed-into" my '{} block?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could pass `Quotes` into something inside a quote would be:

```
// using quotes: Quotes
'{
  val a = sth
  someRuntimeMethod(
    ${ someCompileTimeMethod('{ a })(using quotes) }
  )
}
```

You can put `${}` inside `'{}` and vice-versa. What you couldn't do is

```
// using quotes: Quotes
'{
  someCompileTimeMethod(using quotes) // quotes from outside of '{}
}
```

because it would have to generate runtime code which would expect value available only during compilation (and valid only for this context!).

For some types (usually primitives) you would have `given ToExpr[A]` which would allow you to turn `A` value into `Expr[A]` and use that in `'{}` (basically letting you define inside some value a macro and then just use it in a quoted code), but `Quotes` is not such type. Even if you manually constructed some value of `ToExpr[Quotes]` it would almost certainly be broken.

So either use `${}` inside `'{}` or write a call to `inline def` method inside `'{}` so that compiler would create a new nested `Quote` and pass it for you.